# Unable to add Icons to the first 3 list item in android ListView?

Tags: android, json, listview, icons

recently, I've build a app that I can retrieve the results from the web via json. What it displays is a simple informations. I thought to myself, the custom listview looked simple with only texts, so what I want to do now is to add icons to the left side of the listitem for the first 3 list items only, but things turn complicated,since I've got the json data from the web. I'm finding it difficult to implement the logic to the current code. Afterall, All I want to do is to add icons to the first 3 itemlist. I've set up my sample code below (sorry for the untidy code!).

Is it possible to set the logic within the current code ? Or should I start over again ? Are there some solution ?

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonobject) {

        try {

            // Locate the array name in JSON

            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("infolist");

            world = new ArrayList<InfoListData>();
            // Create an array to populate the spinner
            worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                InfoListData worldpop = new InfoListData();
                worldpop.set_loto_date(jsonobject.optString("loto_date"));
                worldpop.set_info_id(jsonobject
                        .optString("takarakuji_id"));
                worldpop.set_numbertimes(jsonobject.optString("id"));
                worldpop.set_title(jsonobject.optString("title"));
                world.add(worldpop);

                worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("title") + "\n"
                        + jsonobject.optString("info_date"));

            }

            str = jsonarray.toString();
            try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = null;
                    json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    //altering the
                    map1.put("name", json.getString("name"));
                    String dates =  json.getString("loto_date");
                    //dates= dates.replace("-", "year");
                    dates =  replaceCharAt(dates ,4,"year");
                    dates =  replaceCharAt(dates ,7,"month");
                    dates  = dates+="day";

                    map1.put("info_date",dates);
                    String _titles = json.getString("title");

                     map1.put("title", "("+_titles+")");

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList//
                    arrList.add(map1);
                }


            } catch ( JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

//I'm setting up the data in here,but I'm not sure how to set the icons to the 
 current code

```
            ListView mySpinner = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewpo);
            //try the step 5 in here
            if(!arrList.isEmpty()){

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(InfoListActivity.this, arrList,
                        R.layout.customlistforinfo, new String[] {"name", "title", "info_date"},
                        new int[] {R.id.infoname,R.id.infontitle, R.id.dayk});

                mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to make your own custom adapter for the listview to add an image in the listview. You are going to want to extend ArrayAdapter. Here is some code I wrote a while back that does basically exactly what you are trying to do (I think). Hopefully this will help you out a bit. Cheers

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StandingsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResidentialCollege>{

  public StandingsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ResidentialCollege> colleges) {
    super(context, R.layout.standings_row_layout, colleges);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.standings_row_layout, parent, false);

    ResidentialCollege college = (ResidentialCollege) getItem(position);
    TextView collegeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.standingsTextView);
    collegeView.setText(getDisplayName(college.getName()));

    TextView scoreView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tyngScore);
    scoreView.setText("" + getDisplayScore(college.getScore()));


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.resCollegeImage);
    imageView.setImageResource(college.getImgResource());

    return view;

  }

  //generate a string to display from a given residential college name to avoid
  //long names messing up the display. E.G Johnathan Edwards
  private String getDisplayName(String name) {
    if(name.length() > 10){
      return (name.substring(0, 7).toUpperCase() + " ...");
    }
    else return name.toUpperCase();
  }

  //to get rid of the .0's at the end of the scores that are integers.
  //Came at the cost of allowing scores to have .5's forcing floating point numbers.
  private String getDisplayScore(Double score){
    if((score % 1) == 0){
      return "" + score.intValue();
    }
    else{
      return "" + score;
    }
  }

  public void updateStandings(ArrayList<ResidentialCollege> newResList) {
      this.clear();
      for(ResidentialCollege res : newResList){
        this.add(res);
      }
      this.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  //perform a simple insertion sort(only 12 elements, so should be fast enough)
  public ArrayList<ResidentialCollege> sortByScore(ArrayList<ResidentialCollege> listToSort){
    ArrayList<ResidentialCollege> sorted = new ArrayList<ResidentialCollege>();
    sorted.add(listToSort.get(0));
    listToSort.remove(0);

    for(ResidentialCollege college : listToSort){
      for(int i = 0; i < sorted.size(); i++){
        if(college.getScore() >= sorted.get(i).getScore()){
          sorted.add(i, college);
          Log.d("inserted:", college.getName() + " " + "at position " + i);
          break;
        }
        //add it to the end it has the lowest score seen so far.
        else if(i == (sorted.size() - 1)){
          sorted.add(college);
          Log.d("appended:", college.getName() + " " + "at position" + i);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return sorted;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will see what I can do!